# Create a function iterating in Panda's Dataframe rows to replace null values

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, iterator

I have a DataFrame with some null values that I want to substitute with mean values that I have in other DataFrame. I've created a function that it should later be implemented with a lambda but I keep getting an error.

I Have a DataFrame like this:

| CustomerType | Category | Satisfaction | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Not Premium | Electronics | Not Satisfied | NaN |
| Not Premium | Beauty | Satisfied | NaN |
| Premium | Sports | Satisfied | 38.0 |
| Not Premium | Sports | Not Satisfied | NaN |

That i need to fill with this data:

| CustomerType | Satisfaction | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Not Premium | Not Satisfied | 32.440740 |
| Not Premium | Satisfied | 28.896348 |
| Premium | Not Satisfied | 43.767723 |
| Premium | Satisfied | 44.075901 |

So I've created a **function**:

```
def fill_age(x):
if x.isnull()== True:
    return[(grp.CustomerType==x.CustomerType) | (grp.Satisfaction==x.Satisfaction)]['Age'].values[0]
```

That I would like to apply to my dataframe using a **lambda function** to iterate through all the rows:

```
df['Age'] = [df.apply(lambda x: fill_age(x) if np.isnan(x['Age']) else 
                                            x['Age'], axis=1) for x in df]
```

But i keep getting **this error**:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Can anyone of you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should [`try avoid use apply`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-not-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code), so we could use instead:

```
df['Age'] = df['Age'].fillna(
    df.groupby(['CustomerType', 'Satisfaction'])['Age'].transform('first')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you are calling incorrectly `apply` in your `DataFrame` and that `fill_age()` are working correctly on `df["Age"]` values, you need to replace this statement, just to evaluate `x` and asign a determined value (current *Age* or to be replace with external data) then checking by `else-if` conditional, this code shouldn't return errors

```
df["Age"] = df["Age"].apply(lambda x: fill_age(x) if np.isnan(x) else x)
```

Comment: Still not working, pretty sure the error is on the fill_age function. I get: "TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''. "